# Moving/Appending Asyncfileupload with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an index.aspx and loading default.aspx like this.

```
$('#slide_2').load('default.aspx');
```

I need a fileupload in default.aspx

`<cc1:AsyncFileUpload ID="UrunResimFileUpload" ClientIDMode="AutoID" UploaderStyle="Traditional" Width="100px" runat="server" OnUploadedComplete="UploadComplete" OnClientUploadStarted="uploadstarted" OnClientUploadComplete="showConfirmation"  />`

it is not working. Cause jquery load...

So I wrote that code to index.aspx, and made fileupload's position absolute. changed top and left positions. This is a solution, but I don't want this.

I'm wanting another solution, like this;

```
$('#a_div_in_default.aspx').html($('#fileupload_div'));
```

How can we do this?

Edited all post. Is this explanatory?

Comment: I, actually, didn't understood what you want but try this $('#fileupload_newplace').html($('#fileupload_oldplace').html());

Comment: You understood true. I need something like this. But ajaxcontroltoolkit, generates 'clientid's. When I change it, like your advice. It is not working.

Comment: nether understand what is your problem ! what is that with default and index page ? please give more details.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery).  I have done this with GWT, but my recommendation is to go with a plugin, rather than custom code.  My answer is to change your approach that way.

Even with GWT it had a built-in mechanism as it's a common task and the custom code route is a lot of work.

I work with jQuery, but not the .Net stuff.  Here is a [tutorial](http://www.dotnetjalps.com/2011/12/async-file-upload-with-jquery-and.html) entitled: "Async file upload with jquery and ASP.NET" for you showing you how to do this using a jQuery plugin.

The reason I found that using plugins was better was because doing a custom solution meant you had to do all the coding for every feature you want, rather than using one that had features built-in.

Comment: Yes, it is the way. But I dont want this way. Actually, I solved the problem.I'm moving it. I want to know, why asyncfileuploader doesnt work, and how can we fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Why use ajaxcontroltoolkit and Jquery together? Just refer Jquery library file and do your stuff. You can implement this http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/

Comment: Yes, it is the way. But I dont want this way. Actually, I solved the problem.I'm moving it. I want to know, why asyncfileuploader doesnt work, and how can we fix it.